# A function that detects the parameter type, value, and the name and return value of another function?

Tags: c++, function, arguments

I am wondering if how I can write a function to detect the parameter type, value and function name and return value of another function.

For example. I have a function:

```
double average(string datapath, double *data, int numofinput)
{
   // some code here
}
```

I want to have another function, such as detector(), which can be inserted into the function to be detected, like

```
double average(string datapath, double *data, int numofinput)
{

   // some code here
   detector();
}
```

and the detector will return:

```
name: average
returned value: 2.43
pathname: string='C:/Users/Nick/Data/'
data: pointer=0x0065
numofinput: int=17
```

Somthing like that. Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks.
Nick

Comment: wait, you would even want `detector` to show you the return value **before** you actually return anything???

Comment: Sorry, put the detector() after the function is executed.

Comment: so now you want it to execute after `return`? how?

Comment: It might be *technically* possible to do this, but it would require some seriously ugly macros. Your function definitions would have to be completely switched out with a macro that only "sortof" looks like a function definition, and your return statement would have to be switched out with a macro that stored the return value immediately before returning it, but that might require that you pass the type into the macro and...yeah, it'd get really ugly really fast.

Comment: You would need a reflection mechanism which does not exist in standard C++. On the other hand, some C++ variants, such as C++/CLI, have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this can't be done:

- `detector` would need to show the return value before you actually return anything, which is same as mind reading
- when a binary is built, the names of the functions are not available inside it (in general, except for exports)
- your `average` function might not be a function at all, as compiler could inline it.

For specific cases, however, you could be able to get this information - under assumption that you have debug symbols available, which in general you don't.

Comment: So when this average function gets called, can I at least know the input arguments' type and value?

Comment: Without debug symbols, no. They can be provided in many different ways, depending on number of parameters, optimizations, etc. Type info is also lost in general. You will not find a type name in the binary.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an (untested) idea:

```
#define DETECTOR(name, ...) detector_wrapper(name, #name, ##__VA_ARGS__)

template <typename R, typename ...Args, typename ...Brgs>
R detector_wrapper(R(&f)(Args...), char const * name, Brgs &&... brgs)
{
    auto && result = f(std::forward<Brgs>(brgs)...);

    std::cout << "Function name: " << name << std::endl
              << "Return type:   " << demangle(R) << std::endl 
              << "Return value:  " << result << std::endl;

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
double d = DETECTOR(average, path, data, n);
```

With a bit more work you can also print the types of the arguments and their values, though *not* their names (obviously, since the names are not part of the declaration, only of the definition).

Comment: `return std::forward<decltype(result)>(result);` (untested).

Comment: this means that ALL calls would have to be wrapped instead of instrumenting just the function.

Comment: additionally, unless I missed something, you are calling non-variadic `f` as variadic - this wouldn't work, would it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's another way to do it, including printing parameter names and types. It is not very elegant for two reasons:

1. It requires a new macro for every number of parameters you send, and ...
2. It's freaking macros! I've never seen them used elegantly (and this is no exception).

So here goes:

```
#include <iostream>

#define DETECTOR_0ARG_FUNC(RETTYPE, NAME)   \
            RETTYPE NAME() \
            { \
                std::cout << "Function Name: " #NAME << std::endl; \
                std::cout << "Returns: " #RETTYPE << std::endl; \
                std::cout << "No Parameters" << std::endl;

#define DETECTOR_1ARG_FUNC(RETTYPE, NAME, PARAM1TYPE, PARAM1NAME)   \
            RETTYPE NAME(PARAM1TYPE PARAM1NAME) \
            { \
                std::cout << "Function Name: " #NAME << std::endl; \
                std::cout << "Returns: " #RETTYPE << std::endl; \
                std::cout << "Pameter 1 (" #PARAM1TYPE " " #PARAM1NAME "): " << PARAM1NAME << std::endl;

#define DETECTOR_RETURN(RETTYPE, VALUE) \
                RETTYPE __retval = (VALUE); \
                std::cout << "Returning: " << __retval << std::endl << std::endl; \
                return __retval;

#define DETECTOR_END_FUNC   \
            }


DETECTOR_0ARG_FUNC(int, GetFiveFactorial)

    int result = 1;
    for(int i=5; i>0; i--)
    {
        result = result * i;
    }
    DETECTOR_RETURN(int, result)

DETECTOR_END_FUNC


DETECTOR_1ARG_FUNC(int, GetFactorial, int, initVal)

    int result = 1;
    for(int i=initVal; i > 0; i--)
    {
        result = result * i;
    }
    DETECTOR_RETURN(int, result);

DETECTOR_END_FUNC


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GetFiveFactorial();
    GetFactorial(7);
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Function Name: GetFiveFactorial
Returns: int
No Parameters
Returning: 120

Function Name: GetFactorial
Returns: int
Pameter 1 (int initVal): 7
Returning: 5040
```

I kindof don't recommend that you do this. But from a theoretical standpoint, it is possible this way.